# SQL: Referencia dos tablas

Tags: sql

> Tengo la siguiente situacion, estoy tratando de hacer una consulta en
> una tabla (tabla asis) donde tenemos asistencias por 5 dias:
> as1....as5 en estas asistencias pueden haber los siguientes datos:
> "."= presente    "/"= falta    "-"= retardo    la cuestion es la
> siguiente, quiero almacenar la suma de cada  dato en otra tabla (tabla
> pro), estecaso habrian 3 columnas prepro=(para la suma de presente)     falpro=(para la suma de falta)     retpro=(para la suma de retardo)
>
> ```
>  tengo el siguiente codigo de consulta pero no me funciona
> ```

```
update asis set pasipro = pasipro+1 where as1asis  = '.' ;   
update asis set pasipro = pasipro+1 where as2asis  = '.' ;   
update asis set pasipro = pasipro+1 where as3asis  = '.' ;   
update asis set pasipro = pasipro+1 where as4asis  = '.' ;   
update asis set pasipro = pasipro+1 where as5asis  = '.' ;   

update asis set pfalpro = pfalpro+1 where as1asis  = '/' ;     
update asis set pfalpro = pfalpro+1 where as2asis  = '/' ;    
update asis set pfalpro = pfalpro+1 where as3asis  = '/' ;  
update asis set pfalpro = pfalpro+1 where as4asis  = '/' ;    
update asis set pfalpro = pfalpro+1 where as5asis  = '/' ;    

update asis set retpro = retpro+1 where as1asis  = '-' ;    
update asis set retpro = retpro+1 where as2asis  = '-' ;    
update asis set retpro = retpro+1 where as3asis  = '-' ;   
update asis set retpro = retpro+1 where as4asis  = '-' ;     
update asis set retpro = retpro+1 where as5asis  = '-' ;
```

> las consultas de arriba me marcan el error: ORA-00936: falta una expresi¾n, lo que creo que esta fallando es el hacer la referencia entre las dos tablas ya que las as1...as5 se encuentran en una tabla y la suma de los datos los quiero almacenar en la tabla pro
>
> La tabla y atributos son los siguientes

```
drop table asis cascade constraint;
drop table pro cascade constraint;    
create table asis (
idasis varchar2 (10) not null,
as1asis varchar2 (3) not null,
as2asis varchar2 (3) not null,
as3asis varchar2 (3) not null,
as4asis varchar2 (3) not null,
as5asis varchar2 (3) not null,
cescasis varchar2 (12) not null,
constraint pk1_asis primary key(idasis),
constraint fk1_asis foreign key(cescasis) references cesc(idcesc));

create table pro (
idpro varchar2 (10) not null,  
pasipro number(3) not null,
pfalpro number(3) not null,
retpro number(3) not null,
nspro number(3) not null,
cepro varchar2 (10) not null,
asispro varchar2 (10) not null,
constraint pk1_pro primary key(idpro),
constraint fk1_pro foreign key(asispro) references asis(idasis));

insert into asis values('AS1', '.', '/' , '.', '/', '.','C1');
insert into asis values('AS2', '/', '/' , '-', '.', '.','C2');
insert into asis values('AS3', '.', '.' , '.', '/', '-','C3');
insert into asis values('AS4', '.', '-' , '/', '.', '.','C4');
insert into asis values('AS5', '-', '.' , '.', '.', '.','C5');

insert into pro values('P1', 0, 0, 0 , 0 ,'C1','AS1');
insert into pro values('P2', 0, 0, 0 , 0 ,'C2','AS2');
insert into pro values('P3', 0, 0, 0 , 0 ,'C3','AS3');
insert into pro values('P4', 0, 0, 0 , 0 ,'C4','AS4');
insert into pro values('P5', 0, 0, 0 , 0 ,'C5','AS5');
```

Comment: Hola, para poder ayudarte nos puedes decir el qué no te funciona?

Comment: las consultas de arriba me marcan el error: ORA-00936: falta una expresi¾n, lo que creo que esta fallando es el hacer la referencia entre las dos tablas ya que las as1...as5 se encuentran en una tabla y la suma de los datos los quiero almacenar en otra tabla diferente

Comment: Pon las tablas que usas y las relaciones que hay entre ellas, así como sus atributos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que te da es por que estas actualizando la tabla asis pero usas campos de la tabla pro sin hacer un **join**, te dejo un ejemplo siguiendo tu misma lógica sin usar join

```
update pro set pasipro = pasipro+ CASE WHEN 
(select 1 from asis where as1asis  = '.' and IDASIS = 'AS1') = 1 THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END
where ASISPRO = 'AS1';

update pro set pasipro = pasipro+ CASE WHEN 
(select 1 from asis where as2asis  = '.' and IDASIS = 'AS1') = 1 THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END
where ASISPRO = 'AS1';

update pro set pasipro = pasipro+ CASE WHEN 
(select 1 from asis where as3asis  = '.' and IDASIS = 'AS1') = 1 THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END
where ASISPRO = 'AS1';

update pro set pasipro = pasipro+ CASE WHEN 
(select 1 from asis where as4asis  = '.' and IDASIS = 'AS1') = 1 THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END
where ASISPRO = 'AS1';

update pro set pasipro = pasipro+ CASE WHEN 
(select 1 from asis where as5asis  = '.' and IDASIS = 'AS1') = 1 THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END
where ASISPRO = 'AS1';
```

Además te dejo el ejemplo funcional en el [siguiente link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eca520/8/6)

También te invito a que investigues acerca de los **triggers**, por el tipo de esquema que tienes planteado te facilitaría mucho el trabajo, lo puedes usar cuando actualizan la tabla **asis** que automaticamente te actualice la tabla **pro**. Saludos